# How to reload my Python source file, when interactively interpreting it with "python -i"

Tags: python

When writing or debugging a Python program, I really like using the `-i` command line switch to be able to directly inspect my functions without having to run everything from start to finish.

However, whenever I make a change to the code I have to close and restart my interactive session, losing all temporary variables that I might have defined. **How do I reload my source file from within the python interpreter?**

---

The builtin function `reload` looks like it was made for this, but I can only use it with named modules:

```
>> import my_prog
>> print my_prog.x
-- prints an error, because x is not defined --

-- edited my_prog.py to add the x global now...
>> reload(my_prog)
>> print my_prog.x
-- prints x
```

However, if I instead to do a `from my_prog import *` in the beginning reload doesn't work, and doing the import again also has no effect.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This has to do with the way Python caches modules.  You need a module object to pass to reload and you need to repeat the import command.  Maybe there's a better way, but here's what I generally use:
In Python 3:

```
>> from importlib import reload
>> import my_prog
>> from my_prog import *
*** Run some code and debug ***
>> reload(my_prog); from my_prog import *
*** Run some code and debug ***
>> reload(my_prog); from my_prog import *
```

In Python 2, reload is builtin, so you can just remove the first line.

Comment: Well thanks!  @smaplebias has a more thorough description for those who are interested in the finer details.  +1 from me.

Comment: This is a useful trick, thanks.
Beware of stale/leftover symbols though: suppose you have a function `foo()` that calls `bar()` and you decide to rename `bar` to `baz.`
Only you forgot to edit `foo`'s body, so it still calls `bar()` (which is still valid after a reload).
Before you know it, you've spent half a day debugging this.

Answer (score 11):

When you use `from my_prog import *` you're pulling symbols into the interpreter's global scope, so `reload()` can't change those global symbols, only module-level attributes will be changed when the module is recompiled and reloaded.

For example: **myprog.py**:

```
x = 1
```

In interepreter:

```
>>> import myprog
>>> myprog.x
1
>>> from myprog import x
>>> x
1
```

Now edit `myprog.py` setting `x = 2`:

```
>>> reload(myprog)
>>> myprog.x
2
>>> x
1
```

Repeat the `from myprog import *` to pull the symbols to global scope again:

```
>>> reload(myprog)
>>> from myprog import *
```

Comment: This is all kind of obsolete without mentioning python 3's breaking change: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10142772/1509695

Answer (score 0):

I got it. For example we enter interative mode using this command:

```
python3 -i filename.py
```

Then reload it using `importlib` package like this:

```py
from importlib import reload
reload(filename) # Need no quotatiom mark
```