# NameError: name 'reload' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.2.2. When I write a simple program, I meet the problem.

```
>>> reload(recommendations)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    reload(recommendations)
NameError: name 'reload' is not defined
```

How should I do it?

Comment: A "simple program" probably doesn't need `reload`.

Comment: I want to use "reload(recommendations)","recommendations.abc()". But it can't find recommendations

Comment: @MindHacks If you haven't imported recommendations, you don't reload it, you import it. ``import recommendations``. Why did you think you needed to use ``reload()``?

Comment: @geoffspear Most "simple programs" reading files with non-latin characters do need `reload`, unfortunately.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco: if you're thinking of some awful thing you read that involves reload(sys), never do that. Just do `with open('file', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f: do_whatever`. There is absolutely no need to reload() modules in simple programs, or really in *any* python program.

Comment: @geoffspear The problem with using `open`is that most of the times, especially if you are using `pandas`, you just do not use it at all, rather you use other in-built functions to read any file format in. By doing so, you do not specify encoding upon opening line by line and (one of the) solution(s) is to use `reload(sys)`. I agree that it looks cumbersome and it is bad practice but sometimes it does get the job done. If even in those case there are more elegant solutions, I do not know.

Answer (score 183):

You probably wanted [`importlib.reload()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload).

```
from importlib import reload
```

In Python 2.x, this was a [builtin](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#reload), but in 3.x, it's in the `importlib` module.

Note that using `reload()` outside of the interpreter is generally unnecessary, what were you trying to do here?

Comment: Thank you, it works. But if i wanna use the reload,i must import the file every time?

Comment: @MindHacks: What "file" are you talking about?

Comment: @MindHacks: `imp` is a module, not a file.  (It's built into the interpreter core and does not correspond to any file.)  And yes, to use `imp.reload` you have to import `imp`, but that isn't a big deal.

Comment: @MindHacks You need to import ``imp`` where you use ``reload()``, yes. That's how namespacing works. Why would you want to reload a module outside of the interactive prompt anyway?

Comment: Thanks, but sigh. Why are they not trying to make the shell more useful?

Comment: @MindHacks See my answer.

Answer (score 13):

An update to @Gareth Latty's answer. `imp` was depreciated in Python 3.4. Now you want `importlib.reload()`.

```
from importlib import reload
```

Answer (score 11):

Try [`importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload).

> Reload a previously imported module. The argument must be a module object, so it must have been successfully imported before. This is useful if you have edited the module source file using an external editor and want to try out the new version without leaving the Python interpreter.

```
from importlib import reload

reload(module_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you need either `importlib.reload(module)` or at some earlier point you need to `from importlib import reload`. But you can hide the `from importlib import reload` in an initialization file. Make sure that `PYTHONSTARTUP` is defined in your shell. For example,

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/python/startup.py
```

might a reasonable line to add to your `~/.bash_profile`, if your shell is bash, and depending on where you store your python files. (If you’re following these instructions, start a new terminal window at this point so that the line is executed.) Then you can put the line

```
from importlib import reload
```

in `~/python/startup.py` and it will happen automatically. (Again, if you’re following along, start a new python session at this point.) This might look a bit complex just to solve this one problem, but it’s a thing you only have to do once, and then for every similar problem along the lines of “I wish python would always do this”, once you find the solution you can put it in `~/python/startup.py` and forget about it.