# Get Output From the logging Module in IPython Notebook

Tags: python, logging, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-logging

When I running the following inside IPython Notebook I don't see any output:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug("test")
```

Anyone know how to make it so I can see the "test" message inside the notebook?

Comment: What version of IPython are you using, since this works in 1.0?

Comment: @ViktorKerkez `ipython3  notebook --version` returns `1.0.0`

Comment: http://imgur.com/1b7nGZz I get this when I try your code.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez: Ya I don't get that, guess I should file an issue...

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Try following:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug("test")
```

According to [logging.basicConfig](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig):

> Does basic configuration for the logging system by creating a
>   StreamHandler with a default Formatter and adding it to the root
>   logger. The functions debug(), info(), warning(), error() and
>   critical() will call basicConfig() automatically if no handlers are
>   defined for the root logger.
>
> **This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers
>   configured for it.**

It seems like ipython notebook call basicConfig (or set handler) somewhere.

Comment: The same occurs in a normal IPython console: it doesn't print anything, unless a root `logger` is created.

Comment: This solution works again in `ipykernel` 4.5 (possibly as early as 4.4) https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1397

Comment: This does not work any more.  Not with the Jupyter Notebook 5.3.0

Comment: Works for me with the following jupyter installation:
```
$ jupyter --version
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : not installed
qtconsole        : not installed
ipython          : 7.18.1
ipykernel        : 5.3.4
jupyter client   : 6.1.7
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : not installed
ipywidgets       : not installed
nbformat         : not installed
traitlets        : 5.0.5
```

Comment: @Sam and others, I also had issues with logging in `jupyter notebooks` and `ipython` sessions. After calling `logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout)`, logging works as usual as far as I can tell. I found the solution [here](https://gist.github.com/wassname/d17325f36c36fa663dd7de3c09a55e74

Comment: Note that a restart of the notebook kernel seems to required before changes in `logging.basicConfig` take effect.

Comment: Note that this set the log level on the root logger, not on any specific handler. You can set the log level on a per-handler basis afterwards

Answer (score 92):

If you still want to use `basicConfig`, reload the logging module like this

```
from importlib import reload  # Not needed in Python 2
import logging
reload(logging)
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG, datefmt='%I:%M:%S')
```

Comment: For anyone trying to do this in Python 3: [`reload` is now `imp.reload`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10142772/2829764)

Comment: as of Python 3.5, you should use [importlib.reload](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/importlib.html) as the imp module is being deprecated.

Comment: If anyone is having trouble with Spyder with logging (where all attempts at modifying logger behavior were unsuccessful), this just ended a day-long goose-chase. https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2572 Thanks a lot !

Comment: `reload` helped me, since I did't see log messages in jupyter console. Grazie)

Answer (score 40):

My understanding is that the IPython session starts up logging so basicConfig doesn't work. Here is the setup that works for me (I wish this was not so gross looking since I want to use it for almost all my notebooks):

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
fhandler = logging.FileHandler(filename='mylog.log', mode='a')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fhandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fhandler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Now when I run:

```
logging.error('hello!')
logging.debug('This is a debug message')
logging.info('this is an info message')
logging.warning('tbllalfhldfhd, warning.')
```

I get a "mylog.log" file in the same directory as my notebook that contains:

```
2015-01-28 09:49:25,026 - root - ERROR - hello!
2015-01-28 09:49:25,028 - root - DEBUG - This is a debug message
2015-01-28 09:49:25,029 - root - INFO - this is an info message
2015-01-28 09:49:25,032 - root - WARNING - tbllalfhldfhd, warning.
```

Note that if you rerun this without restarting the IPython session it will write duplicate entries to the file since there would now be two file handlers defined

Comment: To make this less "gross looking", put the code in a module on your python path, and import it. Prettier and easy to upgrade in the future.

Comment: Or use logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf') and put all setup in there.

Answer (score 29):

Bear in mind that stderr is the default stream for the `logging` module, so in IPython and Jupyter notebooks you might not see anything unless you configure the stream to stdout:

```
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s : %(message)s',
                     level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)

logging.info('Hello world!')
```

Answer (score 23):

What worked for me now (Jupyter, notebook server is: 5.4.1, IPython 7.0.1)

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger('Something')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Now I can use logger to print info, otherwise I would see only message from the default level (`logging.WARNING`) or above.

Comment: Yes, that works. One *has* to run `basicConfig()` tp make it work.

Answer (score 19):

As of logging version 3.8 a `force` parameter has been added that removes any existing handlers, which allows `basicConfig` to work.  This worked on IPython version 7.29.0 and Jupyter Lab version 3.2.1.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    force = True)
logging.debug("test")
```

After redirecting logs the REPL console, now each keystroke may emit it's own logging message. For example, REPL [ptpython](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/ptpython) begins emitting these log messages after each keystroke.

```
>>> h
DEBUG:parso.python.diff:line_lengths old: 1; new: 1
DEBUG:parso.python.diff:diff parser start
DEBUG:parso.python.diff:-> code[replace] old[1:1] new[1:1]
DEBUG:parso.python.diff:line_lengths old: 1; new: 1
DEBUG:parso.python.diff:parse_part from 1 to 1 (to 0 in part parser)
DEBUG:parso.python.diff:-> code[replace] old[1:1] new[1:1]                                                                                                                            [F2] Menu - CPython 3.8.10
DEBUG:parso.python.diff:diff parser end
DEBUG:parso.python.diff:parse_part from 1 to 1 (to 0 in part parser)
DEBUG:parso.python.diff:diff parser end
DEBUG:asyncio:Using proactor: IocpProactor
>>> h
```

The REPL becomes so noisy it's unusable.

These global logger instances can be quieted by setting the log levels to something less verbose like `logging.WARNING`.

```py
>>> logging.getLogger("parso.python.diff").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
>>> logging.getLogger("asyncio").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

This is probably applicable to other REPLs. Just substitute the appropriate noisy logger name in the call to `getLogger`.

Comment: Please someone delete all the outdated answers. This is the way! Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

You can configure logging by running `%config Application.log_level="INFO"`

For more information, see [IPython kernel options](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/kernel.html#configtrait-Application.log_level)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your help. You might want to make your answer even better by adding some explanation.

Comment: This was actually the most useful answer for me!

Comment: Can you add a few lines with an example?  What is the logger handle to invoke to print log messages?

Comment: At least ipython 7.9.0 (or jupyter 6.0.2) ignores the suggested code, since it doesn't support this class from the running console. Run `%config` to see the supported classed, `Application` is not one of them. ipython 7.9.0 here.

Answer (score 5):

I setup a logger for both file and I wanted it to show up on the notebook. Turns out adding a filehandler clears out the default stream handlder.

```
logger = logging.getLogger()

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Setup file handler
fhandler  = logging.FileHandler('my.log')
fhandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fhandler.setFormatter(formatter)

# Configure stream handler for the cells
chandler = logging.StreamHandler()
chandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
chandler.setFormatter(formatter)

# Add both handlers
logger.addHandler(fhandler)
logger.addHandler(chandler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Show the handlers
logger.handlers

# Log Something
logger.info("Test info")
logger.debug("Test debug")
logger.error("Test error")
```

Comment: fyi - here, `logger` is the root logger. i think it's better practice to create a new logger eg with `getLogger(__name__)`. this is recommended by the docs, second paragraph here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects

Answer (score 5):

I wanted a simple and straightforward answer to this, with nicely styled output so here's my recommendation

```py
import sys
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO,
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    stream=sys.stdout,
)
log = logging.getLogger('notebook')
```

Then you can use `log.info()` or any of the other [logging levels](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.info) anywhere in your notebook with output that looks like this

```
2020-10-28 17:07:08 [INFO] notebook - Hello world
2020-10-28 17:12:22 [INFO] notebook - More info here
2020-10-28 17:12:22 [INFO] notebook - And some more
```

Comment: `stream=sys.stdout` worked for me in Jupyter Lab.

Answer (score 1):

#### setup

```py
import logging

# make a handler
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# add it to the root logger
logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)
```

### log from your own logger

```py
# make a logger for this notebook, set verbosity
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel('DEBUG')

# send messages
logger.debug("debug message")
logger.info("so much info")
logger.warning("you've veen warned!")
logger.error("bad news")
logger.critical("really bad news")
```

```
2021-09-02 18:18:27,397 - __main__ - DEBUG - debug message
2021-09-02 18:18:27,397 - __main__ - INFO - so much info
2021-09-02 18:18:27,398 - __main__ - WARNING - you've veen warned!
2021-09-02 18:18:27,398 - __main__ - ERROR - bad news
2021-09-02 18:18:27,399 - __main__ - CRITICAL - really bad news
```

### capture logging from other libraries

```py
logging.getLogger('google').setLevel('DEBUG')

from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
```

```
2021-09-02 18:18:27,415 - google.auth._default - DEBUG - Checking None for explicit credentials as part of auth process...
2021-09-02 18:18:27,416 - google.auth._default - DEBUG - Checking Cloud SDK credentials as part of auth process...
2021-09-02 18:18:27,416 - google.auth._default - DEBUG - Cloud SDK credentials not found on disk; not using them
...
```