# How to use the logging module in Python with gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, logging, gunicorn, python-logging

I have a flask-based app. When I run it locally, I run it from the command line, but when I deploy it, I start it with gunicorn with multiple workers.

I want to use the `logging` module to log to a file. The docs I've found for this are https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html and https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html .

I am confused over the correct way to use logging when my app may be launched with gunicorn. The docs address threading but assume I have control of the master process. Points of confusion:

Will `logger = logging.getLogger('myapp')` return the same logger object in different gunicorn worker threads?

If I am attaching a logging `FileHandler` to my logger in order to log to a file, how can I avoid doing this multiple times in the different workers?

My understanding - which may be wrong - is that if I just call `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`, this will send messages via the root logger which may have a higher default logging level and may ignore debug messages, and so I *also* need to call `logging.basicConfig(logging.DEBUG)` in order for my debug messages to get through. But the docs say not to call `logging.basicConfig()` from a thread. How can I  correctly set the root logging level when using gunicorn? Or do I not need to?

Answer (score 12):

This is my typical Flask/Gunicorn setup. Note gunicorn is ran via supervisor.

wsgi_web.py. Note `ProxyFix` to get a client's real IP address from Nginx.

```
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
from app import create_app
import logging

gunicorn_logger = logging.getLogger('gunicorn.error')

application = create_app(logger_override=gunicorn_logger)
application.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(application.wsgi_app, num_proxies=1)
```

**Edit February 2020**, for newer versions of werkzeug use the following and adjust the parameters to `ProxyFix` as necessary:

```
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
from app import create_app
import logging

gunicorn_logger = logging.getLogger('gunicorn.error')

application = create_app(logger_override=gunicorn_logger)
application.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(application.wsgi_app, x_for=1, x_host=1)
```

Flask application factory `create_app`

```
def create_app(logger_override=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    if logger_override:

        # working solely with the flask logger
        app.logger.handlers = logger_override.handlers
        app.logger.setLevel(logger_override.level)

        # OR, working with multiple loggers

        # for logger in (app.logger, logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy')):
        #     logger.handlers = logger_override.handlers
        #     logger.setLevel(logger_override.level)

    # more

    return app
```

Gunicorn command (4th line) within supervisor conf, note the `--log-level` parameter has been set to `info` in this instance. Note `X-REAL-IP` passed to access `--access-logformat`

```
[program:web]
directory = /home/paul/www/example
environment = APP_SETTINGS="app.config.ProductionConfig"
command = /home/paul/.virtualenvs/example/bin/gunicorn wsgi_web:application -b localhost:8000 --workers 3 --worker-class gevent --keep-alive 10 --log-level info --access-logfile /home/paul/www/logs/admin.gunicorn.access.log --error-logfile /home/paul/www/logs/admin.gunicorn.error.log --access-logformat '%%({X-REAL-IP}i)s %%(l)s %%(u)s %%(t)s "%%(r)s" %%(s)s %%(b)s "%%(f)s" "%%(a)s"'
user = paul
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Comment: But does this solution work when using logging module from another submodule ? 
From inside my code when I do logging.getLogger().info('test'), nothing seems to be logged. I know I can do app.logger.info('test') and it will work, but I'm trying to log something from another module that I don't want to be dependant on flask.

Comment: @Tyrannas - Yes, see comments "working with multiple loggers".

Comment: @pjcunningham Can this be modified to handle logging.getLogger(__name__) use cases? Where __name__ is being used in the getLogger method.

Comment: @BasilMusa - there's an example in the commented out code.

Comment: Hi @pjcunningham , Yes I noticed the commented code, but I was wondering can I simply replace logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy') with logging.getLogger() (i.e. the root logger)?

Answer (score 2):

Each worker is an isolated process with its own memory so you can't really share the same logger across different workers.

Your code runs inside these workers because the master process only cares about managing the workers.

> The master process is a simple loop that listens for various process
>   signals and reacts accordingly. It manages the list of running workers
>   by listening for signals like TTIN, TTOU, and CHLD. TTIN and TTOU tell
>   the master to increase or decrease the number of running workers.

In Gunicorn itself, there are two main run modes

- Sync
- Async

So this is different from threading, this is multiprocessing.

> However since Gunicorn 19, a threads option can be used to process requests in
>   multiple threads. Using threads assumes use of the gthread worker.

With this in mind, the logging code will be written once and will be invoked multiple times each time a new worker is created. You can use Singelton pattern to ensure the same logger instance is being used inside the same worker.

---

For configuring the logger itself, you just need to follow the normal process of setting the root logger levels and the different loggers levels.

[basicConfig()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) won't affect the root handler if it's already setup:

> This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured for it.

To set the level on root explicitly do

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(name)
```

Then the level can be set on the handler or logger level.

```
handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_path, when='midnight', backupCount=30)                                                                                                             
handler.setLevel(min_level)
```

You can check this similar answer for logging related details
[Set logging levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537905/set-logging-levels)

More Resources :

http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html

Answer (score 0):

By default, Gunicorn only configures the `gunicorn.error` logger. You can use [the `logconfig_dict` option or its equivalents](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#logconfig) to change this.

Create a file `gunicorn.conf.py`:

```py
logconfig_dict = {
    "root": {"handlers": ["error_console"], "level": "INFO"},
    "loggers": {},
}
```

This will configure the root logger to log to stderr. The default handler configured in [`gunicorn.glogging.CONFIG_DEFAULTS`](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/430dcdd997b955fa1a8569a07d9cdcbac686fb35/gunicorn/glogging.py#L48-L86) is used. `loggers` must be specified as an empty dictionary to avoid overwriting the loggers that gunicorn prior to loading `logconfig_dict`.

Gunicorn will automatically load this file if it is in the current working directory. Alternatively, use `-c /path/to/gunicorn.conf.py` to select the configuration file.

If you want to avoid creating a separate configuration file, try this command line argument:

```
gunicorn --log-config-json <(echo '{"root": {"handlers": ["error_console"], "level": "INFO"}, "loggers": {}}')
```

You need the empty `loggers` key to avoid duplicate log messages from Gunicorn itself.