# Logging module with gunicorn

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, gunicorn, python-logging

I am running my code using gunicorn like this way :

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:6435 --access-logfile=allOuts.log --error-logfile=allErs.log --certfile=cert.pem --keyfile=key.pem --ssl-version=5  --ciphers=EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH app:app -w=5 --timeout=500 --daemon
```

And my logging module code is :

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', filename='/app/python/logs/firstlogs.log', filemode='w')

# create console handler and set level to debug
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s\n')

# add formatter to ch
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

# add ch to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)
```

But I can only see some logs. My intuition is I am able to see some logs which are only from one particular worker. How do I direct logs from all workers to same log file? Or how can i maintain different log files for different workers?

I went through a similar question here : [How to use the logging module in Python with gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53548536/how-to-use-the-logging-module-in-python-with-gunicorn) but could not find a solution