# How to log custom messages from code using gunicorn

Tags: python-3.x, gunicorn

I have a gunicorn application running locally, and it does log requests to a text file. What I don't understand is how to log messages to the gunicorn log file from my gunicorn application. To start my app, I use a command like `% gunicorn --workers=2 test:app --reload --log-file log.txt --log-level 'debug'`

I'd like to have code like this:

```
def app(environ, start_response):

    path = environ.get("PATH_INFO")

    if path == "/abc":
        logging.info(f'user requested {path}')
```

And have gunicorn write an info log entry if that's appropriate to the level.

I checked [the documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#logconfig), and I see that gunicorn uses a class `gunicorn.glogging.Logger` to log, but I don't see any documentation on how to instantiate that class or use it to log my own messages.

Answer (score 0):

To log to the gunicorn log file, you must import logging and get a logger using the string "gunicorn.error"

```
import logging

gunicorn_logger = logging.getLogger('gunicorn.error')
```

and then you can do

```
gunicorn_logger.warning(f'returned 404 for: {path}')
```

Source
[How to use the logging module in Python with gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53548536/how-to-use-the-logging-module-in-python-with-gunicorn)