# How to logging with different severity levels in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-functions, stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I had deployed Cloud Functions with runtime python37. My question is how to print or logging with different `severity` and same `execution_id`, which could be easy to filter by log level via *Stackdriver Logging* interface.

By default, `print` will use the same `execution_id`, but I couldn't specify the `severity`.[image]

I had tried both `logging` and `google-cloud-logging`, but they couldn't record the `execution_id` which is useful for debugging GCF.
[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you really want execution id that `print` would take by default, it's available in `request.headers.get("Function-Execution-Id")` for https triggered function and for background function, it is same as `context.event_id`. So you can modify [llompalles's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54675002/4755194) and create Resource inside the function and add execution id to the resource

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no way to add the `execution_id` to the logs entries. But following the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54628438/7757976) you can easily filter the logs entries belonging to the same function execution in the Stackdriver Logging interface.

With this Cloud Function code:

```
import time
from google.cloud import logging
from google.cloud.logging.resource import Resource

identifier = str(time.time())

log_client = logging.Client()

log_name = 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions' 
resource = Resource(type="cloud_function", labels={"function_name": "yourCloudFunctionName", "region": "yourFunctionLocation"})
logger   = log_client.logger(log_name.format("yourProjectId"))

def hello_world(request):

    logger.log_struct({"message": "message string to log", "id": identifier}, resource=resource, severity='ERROR')

    return 'Wrote logs to {}.'.format(logger.name)
```

Once executed open the log entry in the Strackdriver Logging interface. Display the `jsonPayload` and clicking in the `id` element it will display `Show matching entries`. This will add the filter:

```
resource.type="cloud_function"
resource.labels.function_name="yourFunctionName"
jsonPayload.id="theID"
```

And all the logs entry belonging to this execution will be shown.

Finally, just keep in mind that Cloud Function Python 3.7 runtime is still in beta and might be subject to future changes.

Comment: Should the global `identifier` be initialised once or multiple times for each call?

Comment: The identifier will be initialized once every time the Cloud Function is called. So it will act as a sort of `execution_id`.

Comment: `execution_id` should change on every call, but your `identifier` will only change when the function environment is restarted