# How to group related request log entries GAE python 3.7 standard env

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, logging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I'm using Google App Engine python 3.7 standard and i'm trying to group related request log entries.
According to the [Writing Application Logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/writing-application-logs) documentation, I should:

> Set the trace identifier in the LogEntry trace field of your app log
>   entries. The expected format is
>   projects/[PROJECT_ID]/traces/[TRACE_ID]

Where/How should use LogEntry?

The [Stackdriver Logging documentation](https://google-cloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging/usage.html) doesn't show how it's possible. Am I missing something?

Code examples would be much appreciated.

[UPDATE]
Following [Duck Hunt Duo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11316432/duck-hunt-duo) advice, I tried the following, without any success:

```
    trace_id = request.headers.get('X-Cloud-Trace-Context', 'no_trace_id').split('/')[0]
    client = logging.Client()
    logger = client.logger('appengine.googleapis.com%2Fstdout')  # Not shown
    # logger = client.logger('projects/{}/logs/stdout'.format(GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT)) # error
    # logger = client.logger('projects/{}/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fstdout'.format(GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT)) # error

    logger.log_text('log_message', trace=trace_id)
```

**The log doesn't appear in the [GAE service log web console](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at an answer I provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54628438/10561875).

(This answer addresses how to add logging severity to Cloud Functions logs written into Stackdriver, but the basic workflow is the same)

Quoting it:

> [...], you can still create logs with certain severity by using the
>   [Stackdriver Logging Client
>   Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries).
>   Check [this
>   documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/logging/logger.html)
>   in reference to the Python libraries, and [this
>   one](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/logging/usage.html)
>   for some usage-case examples.
>
> Notice that in order to let the logs be under the correct resource,
>   you will have to manually configure them, see [this
>   list](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list#resource-indexes)
>   for the supported resource types.  As well, each resource type has
>   some [required
>   labels](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list#resource-types)
>   that need to be present in the log structure.

**Edit:**

Updating the previous answer with an example for App Engine:

```
from google.cloud import logging
from google.cloud.logging.resource import Resource
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def logger():
    log_client = logging.Client()
    log_name = 'appengine.googleapis.com%2Fstdout'

    res = Resource( type='gae_app',
                    labels={
                        "project_id": "MY-PROJECT-ID",
                        "module_id": "MY-SERVICE-NAME"
                       })

    logger = log_client.logger(log_name)

    logger.log_struct({"message": "message string to log"}, resource=res, severity='ERROR') # As an example log message with a ERROR warning level

    return 'Wrote logs to {}.'.format(logger.name)
```

By using this code as example, and changing the resource type of the log to `appengine.googleapis.com%2Fstdout` should work, and change the `Resource` fields to be the same as in the `gae_app` labels described in [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list#resource-types).

Comment: One clarification - where do you use "YOUR-PROJECT-ID"? 
 log_name.format("YOUR-PROJECT-ID") == log_name == 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions'

Comment: Actually, I have revised my answer and using the `.format("YOUR-PROJECT-ID")` is not necessary, as the project is specified in the `Resource`. You are right on pointing this out as format does nothing in my previous example. I have updated my answer with a code example that works in App Engine, using Flask as a framework.

Answer (score 6):

This is my basic solution:

```
    trace_id = request.headers.get('X-Cloud-Trace-Context', 'no_trace_id').split('/')[0]
    trace_str = "projects/{}/traces/{}".format(os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT'), trace_id)
    log_client = logging.Client()

    # This is the resource type of the log
    log_name = 'stdout'

    # Inside the resource, nest the required labels specific to the resource type
    labels = {
        'module_id': os.getenv('GAE_SERVICE'),
        'project_id': os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT'),
        'version_id': os.getenv('GAE_VERSION')
    }
    res = Resource(type="gae_app",
                   labels=labels,
                   )
    logger = log_client.logger(log_name)
    logger.log_text("MESSAGE_STRING_TO_LOG", resource=res, severity='ERROR', trace=trace_str)
```

After it was working, I wrapped it in a file so it would work similarly to Google's logger for python2.7 .

Here is my_gae_logging.py:

```
import logging as python_logging
import os

from flask import request
from google.cloud import logging as gcp_logging
from google.cloud.logging.resource import Resource

# From GCP logging lib for Python2.7
CRITICAL = 50
FATAL = CRITICAL
ERROR = 40
WARNING = 30
WARN = WARNING
INFO = 20
DEBUG = 10
NOTSET = 0

_levelNames = {
    CRITICAL: 'CRITICAL',
    ERROR: 'ERROR',
    WARNING: 'WARNING',
    INFO: 'INFO',
    DEBUG: 'DEBUG',
    NOTSET: 'NOTSET',
    'CRITICAL': CRITICAL,
    'ERROR': ERROR,
    'WARN': WARNING,
    'WARNING': WARNING,
    'INFO': INFO,
    'DEBUG': DEBUG,
    'NOTSET': NOTSET,
}


def get_trace_id():
    trace_str = None
    try:
        trace_id = request.headers.get('X-Cloud-Trace-Context', 'no_trace_id').split('/')[0]
        trace_str = "projects/{project_id}/traces/{trace_id}".format(
            project_id=os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT'),
            trace_id=trace_id)
    except:
        pass
    return trace_str


class Logging:
def __init__(self):
    self._logger = None

@property
def logger(self):
    if self._logger is not None:
        return self._logger

    log_client = gcp_logging.Client()

    # This is the resource type of the log
    log_name = 'appengine.googleapis.com%2Fstdout'

    # Inside the resource, nest the required labels specific to the resource type

    self._logger = log_client.logger(log_name)
    return self._logger

@property
def resource(self):
    resource = Resource(
        type="gae_app",
        labels={
            'module_id': os.getenv('GAE_SERVICE'),
            'project_id': os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT'),
            'version_id': os.getenv('GAE_VERSION')
        }
    )
    return resource

def log(self, text):
    text = str(text)
    self.logger.log_text(text, resource=self.resource, trace=get_trace_id())

def debug(self, text):
    text = str(text)
    self.logger.log_text(text, resource=self.resource, severity=_levelNames.get(DEBUG), trace=get_trace_id())

def info(self, text):
    text = str(text)
    self.logger.log_text(text, resource=self.resource, severity=_levelNames.get(INFO), trace=get_trace_id())

def warning(self, text):
    text = str(text)
    self.logger.log_text(text, resource=self.resource, severity=_levelNames.get(WARNING), trace=get_trace_id())

def warn(self, text):
    return self.warning(text)

def error(self, text):
    text = str(text)
    self.logger.log_text(text, resource=self.resource, severity=_levelNames.get(ERROR), trace=get_trace_id())

def critical(self, text):
    text = str(text)
    self.logger.log_text(text, resource=self.resource, severity=_levelNames.get(CRITICAL), trace=get_trace_id())


if os.getenv('GAE_VERSION'):  # check if running under gcp env
    logging = Logging()
else:
    # when not running under gcp env, use standard python_logging
    logging = python_logging
```

Usage:

```
from my_gae_logging import logging

logging.warn('this is my warning')
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I've mostly gotten a proof of concept working, but one piece of behaviour that is missing is setting the severity of the parent request log. According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/writing-application-logs "The highest severity from the "child" log entries does not automatically apply to the top-level entry. If that behavior is desired, manually set the highest severity in the top-level entry."
So I think the remaining task is to get the top level entry and update it.

Comment: We might have been doing this the hard way. There is an App Engine logging handler: https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/_modules/google/cloud/logging/handlers/app_engine.html

This already include infrastructure like get_gae_resource() and get_gae_labels()

I'm working through it and may provide another answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll rty

Comment: The problem with this implementation is that it looses sourceLocation. It is unfortunate. You  can work around it by using a part of your message for source location formatted by the Formatter, but that is sub-optimal. Maybe chekcing a stack frame would do

Answer (score 2):

Using the AppEngineHandler from Google Cloud Logging provides much of the infrastructure.  This allows attaching to the python logging module, so that a standard logging import works.

Setting this up is straightforward enough:

```
    # Setup google  cloud logging.
    import logging
    import google.cloud.logging  # Don't conflict with standard logging
    from google.cloud.logging.handlers import AppEngineHandler, setup_logging

    client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
    handler = AppEngineHandler(client, name='stdout')
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    setup_logging(handler)
```

The documentation at https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/usage.html#cloud-logging-handler suggests very similar, but instead of using the AppEngineHandler uses the "CloudLoggingHandler". It also states that the "AppEngineHandler" is for the flexible environment, but this works in the standard python3 environment.

Comment: you can spare one line by using `setup_logging(handler, log_level=logging.INFO)`

Comment: This was working great with google-cloud-logging 1.x - thank you! - but 2.0 seems to have broken it. [Details here.](https://github.com/googleapis/python-logging/issues/110#issuecomment-741010313)

Answer (score 1):

The [Stackdriver Logging Client Library](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/logging/index.html) can be used to achieve this. The [logger.log_text](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/logging/logger.html) function sends a LogEntry object to the API. Example:

```
from google.cloud import logging

client = logging.Client()
logger = client.logger('appengine.googleapis.com%2Fstdout')
logger.log_text('log_message', trace=trace_id)
```

The trace_id should be retrieved from the request headers as the docs mention. The method of doing this will depend on how you're serving requests, but in Flask for example it would be simple as `trace_id = request.headers['X-Cloud-Trace-Context'].split('/')[0]`

Comment: I can't see the log message on the GAE service log web console. Any success doing that?