# Can't find Google AppEngine logs to stdout

Tags: google-app-engine

My python application on the Google App Engine (standard environment) writes some logs to `stdout`.
I used to be able to see them on the Logs Viewer but not anymore.
The default options under the "Log name" drop down menu do not show `stdout`, and I have tried to manually add `logName="projects/airlib-main/logs/stdout"` into the Query Builder but it doesn't find anything.

I solved my problem by NOT using `basicConfig` to configure the logs and rather instantiate my own loggers and use them throughout the application.  The python documentation says that < *This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured* > and maybe the Google App Engine does that now.  My application used to produce logs properly so there might have been a change recently in the way the Google App Engine works in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at the post from the Community: 
[How to group related request log entries GAE python 3.7 standard env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113604/how-to-group-related-request-log-entries-gae-python-3-7-standard-env?rq=1). This post provides you with possible solutions to your `stdout` logging.

For example, as mentioned on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56219234/12767257) - that it's in Python language - there are some methods that you can use to set the `stdout` as the pattern for logs. So, checking this post should assist you in configuring the use of `stdout` on your App Engine.

Let me know if the information helped you!