# Google Error Reporting does not correlate to parent http request

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-error-reporting

I'm using Google App Engine Standard with Python 3. When i click on an error in Google Error Reporting and then click "View Logs", I get taken to Google Logs Viewer/Explorer with something like this `error_group("CObpg_HTfjskb6GA")` as a search filter.

I see the individual log line with the stacktrace but not any logs for the parent request for which this occurred.

[image]

In the docs, they have a screenshot where it does look like we should be able to see the parent http request in which the error occurred: https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/viewing-errors#view_associated_log_entries

Right now when I need to look into an error, I have to do a separate search in logs explorer with part of the error message (in the case of the above example I'd search for `"KeyError: 'c'"`) to find a duplicate log that has a trace id set. Then I'd be able to 'show all logs for trace' and be able to finally see all the logs that lead up to this error.

This feels related to this other issue from before, where logs in general in python3 were not getting correlated like they were in python2: [How to group related request log entries GAE python 3.7 standard env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113604/how-to-group-related-request-log-entries-gae-python-3-7-standard-env)

Logs now get grouped together via `trace`, but as far as I can tell, I cannot set trace on error report logs.

I have my logging setup by doing:

```
    client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
    client.setup_logging()
```

For error reporting I was just getting error reports from `google.cloud.logging`'s integration with the python logger:

```
try:
    # code where an error occurs
except Exception as exc:
    logging.exception(exc)
    raise
```

I've now started trying to use `google-cloud-error-reporting` to see if maybe there are some options in there that I can set to get it to correlate, but I seem to only be able to set a HttpContext & ReportingLocation. There isnt a spot for me to set `trace` or anything like that.

Comment: Log [correlation feature](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/trace-log-integration) is related to tracing. However, this appears to be a limitation in your use case, and it would be better if a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) was submitted.

Comment: It looks like a similar feature request was already submitted 5 years ago https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80475041