# stackdriver logging client library missing severity with python

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

i would like to send more expressive log entries to stackdriver logging from my app engine standard python3 app.
By following the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python) i was able to send my logs to stackdriver and it seems that the timestamp is parsed correctly.

But i'm missing the severity levels. In addition i see no way to link logs for a certain request together to a operation. Something that the java logging seems to be doing out of the box.

For reference here is my code:

```python3
import logging
import os

from flask import Flask
from google.cloud import logging as glog

app = Flask(__name__)
log_client = glog.Client(os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT'))
# Attaches a Google Stackdriver logging handler to the root logger
log_client.setup_logging()


@app.route('/_ah/push-handlers/cloudbuild', methods=['POST'])
def pubsub_push_handle():

    logging.info("stdlib info")
    logging.warning("stdlib warn")
    logging.error("stdlib error")
```

logs resulting in stackdriver:

[image: logs in stackdriver]

As you can see the timestamps and message are available while the severity is strangely missing and it gets classified as 'Any'

Can someone point me in the right direction or is this level of incorporation not yet available?

Thanks for your time!
Carsten

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Cloud Functions Python Logging issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54147483/google-cloud-functions-python-logging-issue)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create your own logger and add the `google-cloud-logging` default handler to it:

```py
import logging

from flask import Flask
from google.cloud import logging as cloudlogging

log_client = cloudlogging.Client()
log_handler = log_client.get_default_handler()
cloud_logger = logging.getLogger("cloudLogger")
cloud_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
cloud_logger.addHandler(log_handler)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/_ah/push-handlers/cloudbuild', methods=['POST'])
def pubsub_push_handle():
    cloud_logger.info("info")
    cloud_logger.warning("warn")
    cloud_logger.error("error")
    return 'OK'
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: I've tried this solution, which is proposed on several other pages, it doesn't work for me, warn is still an error, which version of google cloud logging library do you use?

Comment: This works for "Global" resource typed logs, eg for the ones running on a local machine, but it doesn't work for GAE for some reason.