# Python Cloud Functions add logs to see what is happening

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working with data stored in firestore with Python. I have created a function in my local machine to update my data in firestore but now I want to add a cloud function to update automatically every day using Pub/sub and cloud scheduler.

this is the function I am using:

```
from google.cloud import firestore
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

db = firestore.Client.from_service_account_json('credentials/gc.json')

def update_collection__persons():   
    persons = db.collection(u'collection__persons')
    #person_docs = persons.stream()
    person_docs = [snapshot for snapshot in persons.stream()]

    for person_doc in person_docs:
        person_dict = person_doc.to_dict()
        #last_updated = person_dict['last_updated']
        #last_processed = person_dict['last_processed']
        #dt_last_updated = datetime(1, 1, 1) + timedelta(microseconds=last_updated/10)
        #dt_last_processed = datetime(1, 1, 1) + timedelta(microseconds=last_processed/10)

        #if dt_last_processed < dt_last_updated:
        orders = db.collection(u'collection__orders').where(u'email', u'==', person_dict['email'])
        orders_docs = [snapshot for snapshot in orders.stream()]

        sum_price = 0
        count = 0
        date_add_list = []

        for order_doc in orders_docs:
            order_dict = order_doc.to_dict() 
            sum_price += order_dict['total_price']
            count +=1
            date_add_list.append(order_dict['dateAdded'])
        if count > 0:
            data = {'metrics': {'LTV': sum_price,
                                'AOV': sum_price/count,
                                'Quantity_orders': count,
                                'first_order_date': min(date_add_list),
                                'last_order_date': max(date_add_list)},
                     'last_processed': int((datetime.utcnow() - datetime(1, 1, 1)).total_seconds() * 10000000),
                      'delta_last_updated_last_processed': 0}

            db.collection(u'collection__persons').document(person_dict['email']).set(data, merge = True)
```

I want to put it in google functions, I have two questions here:

1. I am getting an error because when function is triggers - looks like it passes something to it and it’s causing an error because the def is just ().

I have read that I have to put this two variables in my function: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub?hl=en

```
def My_function (event, context):
```

I don't understand what I have to do with this variables, what I have to change in my function to work with this variables?

2. I want to write logs once I run the function in order to know if the function started well and when it finish, also know how to write if something it is wrong, I read that I can do it with google.cloud.logging :[Google Cloud Functions Python Logging issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54147483/google-cloud-functions-python-logging-issue)

But I don't know how to implement this logs in my function, I don't have to much experience in this

Comment: Watch out for the [Cloud Function timeout](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout). Would 9 minutes be enough time for your function to complete its work?

Comment: Yes, 9 minuts would be enough because I will put a condition and there won't be to much data to process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pubsub Cloud Function that calls `update_blanklabelcom__persons()` would look something like this:

```
from google.cloud import firestore
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Service account provided by Cloud Function environment
db = firestore.Client()

def update_blanklabelcom__persons():   
    persons = db.collection(u'collection__persons')
    person_docs = [snapshot for snapshot in persons.stream()]

    for person_doc in person_docs:
        person_dict = person_doc.to_dict()
        orders = db.collection(u'collection__orders').where(u'email', u'==', person_dict['email'])
        orders_docs = [snapshot for snapshot in orders.stream()]

        sum_price = 0
        count = 0
        date_add_list = []

        for order_doc in orders_docs:
            order_dict = order_doc.to_dict() 
            sum_price += order_dict['total_price']
            count +=1
            date_add_list.append(order_dict['dateAdded'])
        if count > 0:
            data = {'metrics': {'LTV': sum_price,
                                'AOV': sum_price/count,
                                'Quantity_orders': count,
                                'first_order_date': min(date_add_list),
                                'last_order_date': max(date_add_list)},
                     'last_processed': int((datetime.utcnow() - datetime(1, 1, 1)).total_seconds() * 10000000),
                      'delta_last_updated_last_processed': 0}

            db.collection(u'collection__persons').document(person_dict['email']).set(data, merge = True) 


def persons_pubsub(event, context):

    print("update blanklabel started")
    update_blanklabelcom__persons()
    print("update blanklabel done")
```

You don't need to use the `event` and `context` variables. They provide extra information about the pubsub event that called the function. To write logs, you can use `print` statements. Anything you print will show up in the Cloud Function logs with a timestamp:

[image]

I deployed this Cloud Function from the console, [as described here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/console). Here's the `requirements.txt`:

```
google-cloud-firestore>=1.4.0
```