# Google Cloud Stackdriver ignores formatting in Python logs

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I'm deploying a Cloud Function with the `python37` runtime. Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54147483/google-cloud-functions-python-logging-issue) I know that I can hook up the Python native logger to Stackdriver logging. So my Cloud Function looks like this:

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format="%(module)s.%(funcName)s: %(message)s", level=logging.INFO)

from google.cloud import logging as glogging
glogging.Client().setup_logging()


def endpoint():
  logging.info("this should be prefixed with main.endpoint")
  return "ok"
```

But when I review the resulting logs in Stackdriver:

1. They're ignoring my formatting, which doesn't happen locally.
2. Each log appears twice: once at its defined severity, and a second time at `ERROR` severity.

It seems that something in `google-cloud-logging` is only processing the message and ignoring everything else. Is there a way to pass it the formatter I defined?

And why are the logs duplicated?

Comment: Are you using the pyhton logging library, or the stackdriver logging library from [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/tasks/creating-logs#writing_log_entries)? I ask because the declaration of severity looks a bit different in your code.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran the code locally, I got this:

```
main.endpoint: this should be prefixed with main.endpoint
this should be prefixed with main.endpoint
Waiting up to 5 seconds.
Sent all pending logs.
```

So, it seems that the library is duplicating logs.