# Kubernetes Logging Wrong Severity

Tags: python, kubernetes

I deployed a python process into a pod of k8. The process makes of a simple logger:

```
import sys

import logging
import logging.handlers
from pathlib import Path
import coloredlogs
from app.core.config import settings 
CONFIG_PATH = Path.joinpath(BASE_PATH, '.configrc') 

LOG_FORMAT = f'%(asctime)s.[{settings.APP_NAME}] %(levelname)s %(message)s'
LOG_LEVEL = settings.dict().get('LOG_LEVEL', logging.INFO)
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


coloredlogs.install(
    level=LOG_LEVEL,
    fmt=LOG_FORMAT,
    logger=LOGGER) 

LOGGER.info("INFO Creating main objects...")
```

However, when I inspect the logs in k8, it always complains that those logs are errors:

```
ERROR 2023-06-01T13:54:37.742688222Z [resource.labels.containerName: myapp] 2023-06-01 15:54:37.[myapp] INFO Creating main objects...


{
insertId: "8xj2l2hwts2f45gt"
labels: {4}
logName: "projects/proj-iot-poc/logs/stderr"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-06-01T13:54:38.596712564Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "ERROR"
textPayload: "2023-06-01 15:54:37.[myapp] INFO Creating main objects..."
timestamp: "2023-06-01T13:54:37.742688222Z"
}
```

Not worth to say that I just usedd out `LOGGER.info("Creating main objects...")` and I expect the log to be just an INFO not and ERROR...

The manifest is as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "11"
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"name":"myapp"},"name":"myapp","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"replicas":1,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app":"myapp"}},"strategy":{"type":"Recreate"},"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"app":"myapp","version":"1.6.1rc253"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"env":[{"name":"COMMON_CONFIG_COMMIT_ID","value":"1b2e6669140391d680ff0ca34811ddc2553f15f7"},{"name":"OWN_CONFIG_COMMIT_ID","value":"52a142ca003ade39a0fd96faffbe5334facc3463"}],"envFrom":[{"configMapRef":{"name":"myapp-config"}}],"image":"europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/mycluster/docker-main/myapp:1.6.1rc253","lifecycle":{"preStop":{"exec":{"command":["/bin/bash","-c","sleep 5"]}}},"name":"myapp","resources":null}],"restartPolicy":"Always"}}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2023-05-26T07:49:37Z"
  generation: 13
  labels:
    name: myapp
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:name: {}
      f:spec:
        f:progressDeadlineSeconds: {}
        f:revisionHistoryLimit: {}
        f:selector: {}
        f:strategy:
          f:type: {}
        f:template:
          f:metadata:
            f:labels:
              .: {}
              f:app: {}
              f:version: {}
          f:spec:
            f:containers:
              k:{"name":"myapp"}:
                .: {}
                f:env:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"name":"COMMON_CONFIG_COMMIT_ID"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                  k:{"name":"OWN_CONFIG_COMMIT_ID"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                f:envFrom: {}
                f:image: {}
                f:imagePullPolicy: {}
                f:lifecycle:
                  .: {}
                  f:preStop:
                    .: {}
                    f:exec:
                      .: {}
                      f:command: {}
                f:name: {}
                f:resources: {}
                f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
            f:dnsPolicy: {}
            f:restartPolicy: {}
            f:schedulerName: {}
            f:securityContext: {}
            f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
    manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
    operation: Update
    time: "2023-05-26T07:49:37Z"
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          f:deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: {}
      f:status:
        f:availableReplicas: {}
        f:conditions:
          .: {}
          k:{"type":"Available"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:lastUpdateTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"Progressing"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:lastUpdateTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
        f:observedGeneration: {}
        f:readyReplicas: {}
        f:replicas: {}
        f:updatedReplicas: {}
    manager: kube-controller-manager
    operation: Update
    subresource: status
    time: "2023-06-03T06:41:24Z"
  name: myapp
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "537412667"
  uid: 375a536e-e39c-4001-a234-e47e812f0bee
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: myapp
        version: 1.6.1rc253
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: COMMON_CONFIG_COMMIT_ID
          value: 1b2e6669140391d680ff0ca34811ddc2553f15f7
        - name: OWN_CONFIG_COMMIT_ID
          value: 52a142ca003ade39a0fd96faffbe5334facc3463
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: myapp-config
        image: europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/mycluster/docker-main/myapp:1.6.1rc253
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/bash
              - -c
              - sleep 5
        name: myapp
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2023-05-26T07:49:37Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2023-06-01T14:33:00Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "myapp-f9bbb5f6d" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  - lastTransitionTime: "2023-06-03T06:41:24Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2023-06-03T06:41:24Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  observedGeneration: 13
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

**EDIT**

Maybe this is realted to:
[GCP and Python Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54147483/google-cloud-functions-python-logging-issue)

Comment: What version of kubernetes are you using? How is the pod deployed? sharing the manifest file would give a better idea

Comment: @Sibtain I use the k8 of gcp. The pod is deployed automatically by using kubectl and injecting into the container env variables. I checked in the pod that the Log level is set t odebug.

Comment: Your code doesn't show you ever calling `LOGGER.info(...)`. Can you provide a [mcve] that reproduces the behavior you're asking about?

Comment: @larsks I did, I mentioned that I used LOGGER.info() to write an informative message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scraping the web, I understood that GCP does not support the logging python painlessy.
I ended up writing my custom logger:

```
"""
General colorized Logger compatible with GCP
"""
import os
import sys
import datetime
import pprint

from typing import TextIO


class CustomLogger:
    BLACK = '\033[0;30m'
    RED = '\033[0;31m'
    GREEN = '\033[0;32m'
    BROWN = '\033[0;33m'
    BLUE = '\033[0;34m'
    PURPLE = '\033[0;35m'
    CYAN = '\033[0;36m'
    GREY = '\033[0;37m'

    DARK_GREY = '\033[1;30m'
    LIGHT_RED = '\033[1;31m'
    BOLD_RED = "\x1b[31;1m"
    LIGHT_GREEN = '\033[1;32m'
    YELLOW = '\033[1;33m'
    LIGHT_BLUE = '\033[1;34m'
    LIGHT_PURPLE = '\033[1;35m'
    LIGHT_CYAN = '\033[1;36m'
    WHITE = '\033[1;37m'
    RESET = "\033[0m"
    pippo = "1"

    def __init__(self, fmt: str = ""):
        self.fmt = f"%(asctime).[{os.getenv('APP_NAME')] %(levelname) %(message)"
        self.terminal_type = os.getenv('TERM') or ""

    def debug(self, message: str = ""):
        out = self.__format(message)
        self.sprint(self.DARK_GREY, message=out)

    def warning(self, message: str = ""):
        out = self.__format(message)
        self.sprint(self.CYAN, message=out)

    def info(self, message: str = ""):
        out = self.__format(message, 'INFO')
        self.sprint(self.GREEN, message=out)

    def critical(self, message: str = ""):
        out = self.__format(message, 'CRITICAL')
        self.sprint(self.BOLD_RED, message=out, file=sys.stderr)

    def exception(self, message: str = ""):
        out = self.__format(message, 'CRITICAL')
        self.sprint(self.LIGHT_RED, message=out, file=sys.stderr)

    def error(self, message: str = ""):
        out = self.__format(message, 'ERROR')
        self.sprint(self.RED, message=out, file=sys.stderr)

    def __format(self, message, level: str = ""):
        now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
        message = pprint.pformat(message)
        return self.fmt.replace("%(message)", message).\
            replace("%(asctime)", now).\
            replace("%(levelname)", level)

    def sprint(self, color, message, file: TextIO = sys.stdout):
        if 'xterm' in self.terminal_type:
            print(color + message + self.RESET)
        else:
            print(message)

LOGGER = CustomLogger()
```

Some code optimization omitted.