# logging basicConfig not having effect in __main__

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I am writing a package that has a `__main__.py` with something like:

```
def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    print(logging.getLogger(__name__))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And I am running it like so:

```
python3 -m my_package
```

And seeing:

```
<Logger __main__ (ERROR)>
```

instead of `INFO`. And so none of my log messages are showing up on the screen.

Why is `basicConfig` not having effect?

Comment: This works fine for me. What code are you using to log a message?

Comment: The usual. logging.info(“something”). Tried setting level to debug and logging.debug didn’t show up either. The level remains set to ERROR for some reason.

Comment: Ok, I have narrowed the reason down to a third-party package that I am using. It might be doing something bad that is causing my basicConfig to not work.

What's a good way to ignore what that package might be doing with logging and enforce my own rules?

Comment: I think I see my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537905/set-logging-levels

basicConfig doesn't work if something else is setting root handler. I should use `getLogger` to get the logger and set its level. Trying now.

Answer (score 3):

Another package I was importing was setting logging upfront, and my `basicConfig` settings were not overriding. I added `force=True` to my `basicConfig` call and it works now.