# Can't see my python logs from ECS in CloudWatch

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, python-logging

I am using MWAA that executes Python task using ECS.
I tried to add logs with `logger.info`, but can't find them in CloudWatch.
I am able to see `logger.warning` logs.

I tried to add:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

to my python task and in my Docker file. (Added as a file with other functions by ENTRYPOINT.)

All my logs in MWAA are set to info.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an AWS issue at all. If you run the same Docker image locally, do you see those logs being output to the Docker console? Get the logs working locally and they will also work when you deploy the docker image to AWS.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works now, I use: 
logging.basicConfig()

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your problem is not on ECS but on the log level, as python logging level is by default `warning`, what you are trying to do is get the `info` logs to be shown, try looking this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537905/set-logging-levels).