# How can I ask jupyter to automatically revert when file has changed on disk

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Hello I am using `jupyter-lab` with the [jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) extension.
This extension allows you to `--sync` different format so that you can edit say a `Rmd` file that will automatically be converted to `ipynb`
This `ipynb` file is loaded in `jupyter`
To update the file opened in jupyter I have to click on "save", I then get the following message

[image]

I then have to click on revert to update from disk.

Is there a way so that the file on disk is automatically "reloaded" each time it changed or say every second and that It s "reverted" automatically ?

Comment: do you have the solution for this case?