# logging is not creating any output?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Here is my code

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug("This is debug")
logging.info("This is info")
logging.warning("This is warning")
logging.error("This is error")
logging.critical("This is critical")
```

This code is not generating any output. I know that logging level is by default to warning, that is why I changed it to `DEBUG` level so that all 5 levels are printed. 
Kindly assist.

Comment: run python -u it might be buffering your log writes.

Comment: It works for me. How do you run it?

Comment: I can't see the output in console (jupyter notebook). Also, how can it save the logs to the file, when I did not mention the file name in ( logging.basicConfig) line.   Thanks

Comment: I don't run jupyter... can't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786912/get-output-from-the-logging-module-in-ipython-notebook

Comment: try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60162528/11430726) does it work?

Comment: @Tanmayagrawal create a new FileHandler and add it to the logger.

Comment: Yes, this thing works. Thanks a lot . But why do I have to create a file handler for this. Root logger should be there by default ? What is the reason for the normal code to not work in jupyter ?