# Logger output in AWS Sagemaker Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, aws-glue, amazon-sagemaker, jupyter-lab

I would like to see the custom logs that I create inside an AWS Sagemaker JupyterLab notebook (that uses a Glue development endpoint). I want to see them as the output of a notebook cell.

I tried with:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.info("I want to see it as output in my notebook cell.")
```

and also with:

```
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
logger = glueContext.get_logger()
logger.info("I want to see it as output in my notebook cell.")
```

but both give no output, in comparison to a `print("Hi")` which correctly gives the "Hi" output on the notebook.

Although I want the logs on the notebook itself, I've also checked if they are available as CloudWatch Logs, but there the logs of my notebook look like `[W 10:42:34.540 NotebookApp] zmq message arrived on closed channel` (in any case, I want them on the notebook, not in CloudWatch).

Many thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am running into the same issue.  I would like to code glue jobs in notebook and then when ready just copy and paste into the Glue console.  Not having a consistent way to log is so annoying.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786912/get-output-from-the-logging-module-in-ipython-notebook for solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
logger.info('that should work :-)')
```

Comment: could you please @pitchblack408 try the proposed solution and let us know if it works? Unfortunately I don't use Sagemaker anymore so I cannot test it.

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to Log messages from the jupyter notebook instances to cloudwatch.

```
pip install watchtower
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError
from watchtower import CloudWatchLogHandler
# Configure the logger
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Create a CloudWatch Logs handler
client = boto3.client('logs', region')
log_group_name = 'log_name'
log_stream_name = 'log_stream_name'
handler = boto3.session.Session().get_credentials()
handler = CloudWatchLogHandler(log_group_name, log_stream_name, client)



# Add the CloudWatch Logs handler to the logger
logger.addHandler(handler)
# Log a message
logger.info('This is an info message')
logger.warning('This is a warning message')
logger.error('This is an error message')
```