# Logging SQL Exceptions on Jupyter Notebook With mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, logging, jupyter-notebook, mysql-connector-python

I'm coding up a Python file that inserts rows into a MySQL table from a dataframe using `mysql.connector`. I'm trying to log each successful request and also the exceptions- I'm using Jupyter Notebook to execute the program. However, I'm not able to see any logging on the notebook- I have manually to go into the MySql database and check what has gone in, and I have no idea which entries haven't been successfully entered. Here is my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
import logging
import math

def upload_to_db(host, database, user, password,
                 tbl_name, col_str, dataframe):

    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=host, database=database, user=user, password=password)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("drop table if exists %s;" % (tbl_name))
        cursor.execute("create table %s (%s);" % (
            tbl_name, col_str))
        data_list = dataframe.to_numpy().tolist()
        for i in range(0, len(data_list)-1):
            row_values = convert_list(data_list[i])
            sql_statement = 'INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s);' % (
                tbl_name, row_values)
            cursor.execute(sql_statement)
            logging.info("SQL statement [" + sql_statement + "] successful")
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        logging.info("Exception: {}".format(err))
```

Why doesn't the python `logging` class show the exceptions or successes on the Notebook?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786912/get-output-from-the-logging-module-in-ipython-notebook for a solution.

Comment: Thanks @NunoMariz that solved my problem!