# How do you print logs in the Chrome console?

Tags: python, logging, jupyter-lab

I have a script that I run in the Jupyterlab. I'm using an external library that creates logs which i can see them in the JupyterLab console. Is there a way to push logs created by that library
and see directly in the Chrome console? I've tried several approaches and no success.
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if this is supported, since I don't believe it is a requirement to run jupyter notebooks using a javascript environment. Normally, you would `console.log()` messages to the browser console in javascript. But perhaps you mean something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786912/get-output-from-the-logging-module-in-ipython-notebook

Comment: Thanks @CodingTil not exactly. Printing in the jupyter console is fine. The challenge is to push the logs to the Chrome console. Thx