# Pip Install Foundations

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, homebrew

I'm working on a Twilio texting program I can't install foundations I keep getting this issue. I've already tried reinstalling pip, easy_setup, pip wheel, django, and python.

I have no idea why i'm still getting this error. I'm running Mac Osx

```
Collecting Foundations==2.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/c4/341b76267c3969b46170f715524259c1c170992253cb7c425d746cb2e322/Foundations-2.1.0.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/l5/k0m1stsn5yz8x0sx_wj4z9qm0000gn/T/pip-install-xi0ft4n3/Foundations/setup.py", line 35, in <module>
    _setEncoding()
  File "/private/var/folders/l5/k0m1stsn5yz8x0sx_wj4z9qm0000gn/T/pip-install-xi0ft4n3/Foundations/setup.py", line 31, in _setEncoding
    reload(sys)
NameError: name 'reload' is not defined

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/l5/k0m1stsn5yz8x0sx_wj4z9qm0000gn/T/pip-install-xi0ft4n3/Foundations/
```

Comment: Maybe it was not properly moved to python 3. On [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10142772/236345) it was pointed out that `reload` was builtin and in 3.x was moved to importlib.

Comment: How would I correct that error and install the required modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Foundations](https://github.com/KelSolaar/Foundations/blob/5c141330faf09dad70a12bc321f4c564917d0a91/setup.py#L77) is only for Python 2.7.

Comment: I've tried uninstalling other version of python and I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: Check version: `python --version`. Use this python for installation: `python -m pip install Foundations`.

Comment: Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.
I thought I deleted python 3 do I need to downgrade anaconda?