# python3 interactive mode live reload

Tags: python, shell, interactive, live

Is it possible a live reload and run while in iteractive mode  of a python_file.py ?

```
 $ python3 -i python_file.py
    >>>

>>>here I am testing behavior and properties of python_file.py
>>>but while interacting here with python_file.py, I am making changes in *python_file.py*
>>>the recent changes of python_file.py are not visible in the current shell
>>>quit()
```

Now I am rerunning the program to see the changes:

````
$ python3 -i python_file.py```
>>>only now I can see the changes that I made in *python_file.py* while the previous shell was open
>>>
````

Is there any option here :

```
$ python3 -i ***-live_reload*** python_file.py
>>>
```

or here:

```
>>> or ask here for ***-live_reload*** python_file.py
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reload my Python source file, when interactively interpreting it with "python -i"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793149/how-to-reload-my-python-source-file-when-interactively-interpreting-it-with-py)

Comment: Indeed the above comment represents a partial answer while in python interactive shell  one gets live reload .But still awaiting to see if exists an option from the bash or other different shell than python.